# How to install 32 bit Ubuntu on 64 bit machine

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit) in 64 bit machine. But I want to use a 32-bit operating system (either 12.04 or 8.04), I tried to do it using bootable pen drive but it failed, while I have alreay changed my OS from 12.10 (64 bit) to 12.04 (64bit) using bootable pendrive. Any kind of help will work.

Comment: If a machine is 64-bit capable it's also 32bit capable.  Just backup and do a clean install of the OS you want.

Comment: please tell if any linux command is there to change a 12.04(64 bit) to 12.04(32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

32 bit operating systems should work fine on 64 bit systems. I think you did something wrong when creating your bootable pen drive.

Maybe this link can help you:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: actually , i made the pen drive bootable using terminal commands, and as i did it earlier for ubuntu 12.04, its perfectly fine.

Comment: also, i need to know installation procedure,as i am using ubuntu 12.04(64 bit) and i have made the bootable pen drive.

Comment: while booting from usb key, it is showing error, though i have set the priority as usb key on top